# Run GUI on remote computer and control it from local computer

Tags: ssh, skype, remote-desktop

**Problem:**

Parents can't operate computer and I'm going overseas. So I'm leaving behind an old laptop with linux on it (let's call it **homecomp**) for video chat. I can teach them to power on and login (thinking of autologin).

Now I want to remotely login to **homecomp**, open skype or hangouts on browser, enter password and make a call to my personal account. I know how to `ssh` and X and export DISPLAY. But I need the gui to be open on both the systems with control on mine.

How do I do it?

Comment: TeamViewer maybe? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Have you tried any of the softwares?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [Desktop Sharing](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/vino/)?

This is a front end for VNC, which will allow you to easily start up a Video Session (I guess that is the point of your question).

Personally I'd stay away from things like Teamviewer (it works, but security, Wine, authentication speak against it)

Comment: Keep in mind that with VNC you may need to set up port forwarding on your router, as well as some sort of DNS service; services such as TeamViewer take care of this automatically

Answer (score 1):

Actually， you can try [teamviwer](https://www.teamviewer.com/zhcn/)

Install it both on your parents' computer and yours.

Answer (score 0):

### NoMachine

Try [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/).

It is the best free remote desktop software. You can enjoy all the remote content, access all devices(printer, usb devices, pendrives, etc) and record what you do in videos for helping your parents with some issue.

Also, it is easy to install and free.

An tutorial on using it over Internet is available at https://www.nomachine.com/getting-started-with-nomachine

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Remmina for remote desktop. Fairly happy with it so far.

As mentioned before, you'll likely have to set up port forwarding in the router if you haven't already.